# How to measure sound volume in dB scale Android

Tags: android, iphone, audio-recording, mediarecorder

We are working on a cross-platform project that requires sound volume sampling on smartphones and analyse the result with as high accuracy as possible, the IPhone developer used iOS implemented functionality of returnning sound power/volume in dB scale calculated by the OS itself. as far as i know there is no equivalent functionality in Android OS.

as of now, I am working on Android with the MediaRecorder class given by the OS, and i use getMaxAmplitude to measure the sound power/volume, i have seen a lot of answers on the net regard how to transfer amplitude to dB scale, the answer that sounded most reasonable was using the formula :

20*Math.log10(amplitude/MAX_AMPLITUDE)

but then i must know what the MAX_AMPLITUDE that can be returned by getMaxAmplitude, thing is that it is diffrent on diffrent devices, for exemple i tested getMaxAmplitude on HTC Desire, and on Samsung Galaxy S3,
on HTC it was reaching 32767 (which i saw in some answer that is the documented max), and on the S3 it was not going beyond 16383 (half of the HTC).

**Q1 :**

is this(the approach discussed above) the correct approach? its just that I read that [the correct way to measure sound power/volume is by calculating RSM and then convert it to dB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129480/how-to-test-sound-level-rms-algorithm), is this how its done on IPhone?

**Q2 :**

no metter if i use RSM or just the Amplitude from getMaxAmplitude, it seems to me that i still need to know whats the highest amplitude i can get from the record hardware, is there a way to know that? or is there a way to somehow go around it?

Comment: this answer might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523301/android-amplitude-value-to-decibel-value

Comment: The Android Compatibility Definition Document states that _"Audio input sensitivity SHOULD be set such that a 90 dB sound power level (SPL) source at 1000 Hz yields RMS of 2500 for 16-bit samples"_. So it seems strange that the amplitude would differ by a factor of two between different devices if all parameters in your test are largely the same. I can't say which of them that is closest to being correct though.

Answer (score 6):

90dBspl is an rms value in the acoustic domain.
The digital level of 2500 rms in a 16bit system is the same as approximately -22dB FS rms (actually -22.35), where 0dBFS rms is a full scale square wave. A full scale sinusoidal in such a system is 0dBFS peak and -3dB FS rms (reaching from -32768 to +32767).

A square wave of +/-2500 can be calculated as:

20 * log ( 2500/32767) = -22.35 dB FS rms

Please note that peaks of sinusoidals are always 3dB higher than the rms level. The only signal that has the same rms and peak level is the square wave.

Now, Android has a requirement of 30dB linearity around 90dBspl, but this linearity shall be +12dB above 90dBspl and -18dB below the same point. Outside this range there can be compression in different ways, depending on which phone model you test.

The guaranteed highest linear level inside an Android phone is -22dBFS +12dB = -10dBFS rms. Above this level it is uncertain. The most common scenario is that the last 7dB of peak headroom are still linear, leading to an acoustic maximum level of 90dBspl + (22-3 dB) = 109dB spl rms for a sinusoidal without clipping (or 112 dB spl peak).

In some phones you will find a peak limiter that reduces the gain above 102dBspl rms. The outcome of this is that you can still record up to the level of saturation for the microphone. This saturation level varies, but it is common to have like 2% distortion at 120dB spl. Above this level the microphone component starts to saturate and clip.

Looking at the other end of the scale:

Small phone microphones are in general noisy. The latest microphones can have a noise floor at -63dB below 0dBPa (94dBspl), but most microphones are between -58 and -60dB below 0dBPa.

How can this be calculated to dBFS rms ?

0dBPa rms is 94dB spl rms. From the statement above we know that 90dBspl rms acoustic level will be recorded at the digital level of -22dBFS rms in Android phones. -63dB below 90dBspl is the same as -22dBFSrms +4dB -63dB = -81dBFSrms. The absolute maximum range of dynamics in a 16 bit system can be approximated to 96dB (or 93dB depending how you see it), so the noise level is at least 12dB above the quantization noise in the digital file.

This is a very important finding for video recording mode. Unfortunately many video applications in Android tend to have too high microphone gain in the recording. This leads to clipping when recording loud music concerts and similar situations. We also know that the microphone itself is good up to at least 120dB. So it would be a good idea for any audio system engineer to make a video recording mode that actually used the whole dynamic range of the microphone. This means that the gain should be set at least 8dB lower. It is always possible to change the rms level afterwards in a video recording if the sound is too soft, but if it is clipped, then you have damaged the recording forever.

So, my message to you programmers is to implement a video recording mode where the acoustic level of 90dB spl rms is recorded at -30dBFSrms or slightly below that. Any maximization can be done afterwards. In this way we could record rock concerts with much better sound. Doing automatic gain control does not help the sound quality. The dynamic range is often too big to be controlled automatically. You get a lot of pumping in the sound. It is better to implement two different video recording modes: Concert mode and speech mode. In speech mode (optimized for a talking person at 1m distance) the recording gain could be even higher than -22dBFSrms for 90dBspl. I would say -12dBFS rms for 90dBspl would be a suitable recording level. (speech at 1m distance has an rms level of approximately 57dB spl and peaks 20-30dB higher).

Björn Gröhn
Audio system engineer at Sony mobile Lund, Sweden

Comment: Hey Björn, thanks for your contribution, all this information is awesome and very deep. However, at least for me, it is too complex and doesn't help achieve the same measuring we get on iPhones.. that's what I think the original goal was. Please don't take me wrong.

Can you help us with a more simple and objective answer find a way to consistently achieve the same amount of decibels converting from amplitude? Or at least how we could determine if something is loud or quiet given an arbitrary range depending on the device.